# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

I am using Magento 2 and porto theme. My issue is with layered navigation.
When I search anything in my store results shows along with custom attribute filters, created through `Store > Attribute > Product`.

When results shows and I click on attribute to filter further ajax loads and nothing happens.
These are the errors I can see in console.

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in /app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Controller/Search/Result/Index.php:132
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /public_html/generated/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Controller/Search/Result/Index/Interceptor.php(24): Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Controller\Search\Result\Index-&gt;execute()
#1 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Controller\Search\Result\Index\Interceptor-&gt;execute()
#2 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action-&gt;dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Controller\Search\Result\Index\Interceptor-&gt;___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#4 /public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Mageplaza\LayeredNa in /public_html/app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/Controller/Search/Result/Index.php on line 132
```

Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is the code on line 132
$result     = ['products' => $products->toHtml(), 'navigation' => $navigation->toHtml()];
I have checked the module the code is fine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages in order to familiarize yourself with the site. Please do so, especially [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your post to include that [mcve]. We cannot debug code we cannot see, or a single line of code totally out of context buried in a comment.

Comment: Have you solve this issue @Usman